# How to override the compareTo method in the rectangle class that compares based on perimeter?

Tags: java

I have a rectangle class here and I need to override the compareTo method so that it compares based on the rectangle's perimeters. I know the current compareTo method I have is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

here is the code:

```
public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
    private double length;
    private double width;
        private double perimeter;


    public Rectangle(double l, double w){
        this.length = l;
        this.width = w;
    } 

    public  double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public  double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

        public void setLength(double l){
            length= l;
        }
        public void setWidth(double w){
            width = w;
        }

    public double getPerimeter(){
        perimeter = 2*(width + length);
                return perimeter;
    }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
                String t=Double.toString(perimeter);
                String o=Double.toString(other.perimeter);
        int comp = t.compareTo(o);

               return comp;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Rectangle: "+ width +" by "+ length ;
        }




}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a string?  Replace "`return comp;`"  with "`return perimeter - other.perimeter;`" and delete the lines creating the `t` and `o` strings.

Comment: but how do I compare the perimeters? I don't understand what you mean by returning perimeter - other.perimeter

Comment: In compareTo you have to return 0, a negative number or a positive number, depending on how you want your rectangles ordered.  Since you want to order your rectangles by perimeter, you can achieve what you want by returning the subtraction of one rectangle from the other (`return perimieter - other.perimeter`).

Comment: You could always give it a try, and if it doesn't work, go back to whatever you're doing.

Comment: @Catherine  *I know the current compareTo method I have is wrong* , what is the current output and what is the expected when you compare two Rectangle objects?

Comment: The other problem is that you're not setting the perimeter in the constructor.

Comment: It only gets calculated when the getPerimeter method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 public int compareTo(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
    return Double.compare(this.getPerimeter(), otherRectangle.getPerimeter());
}
```

Comment: It should use `getPerimeter()` instead, since the code unwisely doesn't update the `perimeter` variable when the length or width is changed.

Comment: that was right, I just wrote it in the traditional way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
You need to use getPerimeter because your calculation logic lies there:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
          return Double.compare(getPerimeter(), other.getPerimeter());
    }
```

Comment: incompatible - `int`, `double`

Comment: can't afford to narrow considering the data loss. **System.out.println((int)(39.2-39.1));**

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran true...your solution's better

Comment: Did you mean to write `,` instead of `-` in the middle of that?  Otherwise, this doesn't compile.

Comment: @DavidWallace - yes, I did. Edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are correct. This answer just adds an array of rectangles and sorts them based on their perimeters using `java.util.Array.sort` to demonstrate that the comparator is working.  Also, the calculation of the perimeter is moved into the constructor, instead of the `getPerimeter` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double perimeter;


    public Rectangle(double l, double w){
        this.length = l;
        this.width = w;
        perimeter = 2 *(width+length);
    } 

    public  double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public  double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public void setLength(double l){
        length= l;
    }
    public void setWidth(double w){
        width = w;
    }

    public double getPerimeter(){
        perimeter = 2*(width + length);
        return perimeter;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
        return Double.compare(perimeter, other.perimeter);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Rectangle: "+ width +" by "+ length ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rectangle [] arrayOfRectangles = new Rectangle [3];
        arrayOfRectangles[0] = new Rectangle(1.0,1.0);
        arrayOfRectangles[1] = new Rectangle(6.0,5.0);
        arrayOfRectangles[2] = new Rectangle(2.0,3.0);
        Arrays.sort(arrayOfRectangles);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayOfRectangles[i]);
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: Be careful talking about "all the other answers".  Your first sentence is currently false, because there's an incorrect answer here.  But even if it were true, somebody could make it false by posting a new answer.  If you want to say something about someone else's answer, it's always best to specify exactly which answer you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Few things -

1. You can evaluate the parameter of a `Rectangle` within the constructor instead of the getter as

   ```
   public Rectangle(double l, double w) {
       this.length = l;
       this.width = w;
       this.perimeter = 2 * (this.width + this.length);
   }
   ```

   and then your `perimeter`s getter and setter be like -

   ```
   public double getPerimeter() {
       return perimeter;
   }

   public void setPerimeter(double perimeter) {
       this.perimeter = perimeter;
   }
   ```
2. You can compare using the `Double` class `compare` method as

   ```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(CompareToRectangle other) {
       return Double.compare(this.perimeter, other.perimeter);
   }
   ```
3. You can test the same using a test method as  -

   ```
   public static void testRectangle() {
       Rectangle first = new Rectangle(2.00, 3.00);
       Rectangle second = new Rectangle(4.00, 3.00);
       if (first.compareTo(second) == 0) {
           System.out.println("Similar rectangles.");
       } else if(first.compareTo(second) == 1) {
           System.out.println("First rectangle bigger than second.");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Second rectangle is bigger than first.");
       }
   }
   ```