# Why does my findMax method gives me the result of the first element of an array instead of the maximum element?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the rectangle with the maximum perimeter using a static findMax method. Somehow it only gives me the the Rectangle i generated in an array not the array with the maximum perimeter. I don't know what's wrong because the compareTo method I overrode seems to be working fine.

here is the code of the rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
    private double length;
    private double width;
        private double perimeter;


    public Rectangle(double l, double w){
        this.length = l;
        this.width = w;
    } 

    public  double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public  double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

        public void setLength(double l){
            length= l;
        }
        public void setWidth(double w){
            width = w;
        }

    public double getPerimeter(){
               perimeter = 2*(length+width);

               return perimeter;
    }




        @Override
    public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
               return Double.compare(this.perimeter, other.perimeter);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Rectangle: "+ width +" by "+ length ;
        }




}
```

And this is the main that has the findMax: it is kinda messy cuz i was testing things out

```
public class Problem1{

    public static <Anytype extends Comparable<Anytype>> Anytype findMax(Anytype[] arr){
                int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
                if ( arr[i].compareTo(arr[maxIndex]) > 0 )
                            maxIndex = i;
            return arr[maxIndex];
        }


              public static void main(String[] args){

        Rectangle[] arr = new Rectangle[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 20);
         r.setWidth((Math.random()*10)+10); 
         r.setLength((Math.random()*10)+10);

         arr[i] = r;
        }

               // Rectangle max = findMax(<Rectangle>[] arr);

                Rectangle max = findMax(arr);
                double maxP =max.getPerimeter();
                System.out.println( "The rectangle that has the max perimeter is "+findMax(arr)+" maxP is "+maxP);
                for(Rectangle rec: arr){
                    System.out.println(rec.getPerimeter());
                    System.out.println(rec);


                }

    }


}
```

Comment: Your `compareTo` method uses the field `perimeter`, which only gets initialized after a call to `getPerimeter()`. I'd suggest scrapping that field, and just using `getPerimeter()` (which will always return the correct perimeter based on the `width` and `height` fields). Or you could update `perimeter` in your length/width setters.

Comment: You can update the getter and setter for your code as suggested here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41906384/1746118

Comment: You've created 5 objects of Rectangle setting length and width, but perimeter is not set anywhere, so every rectangle will have perimeter as 0.0 (default value). So I recommend initalize perimeter in constructor as **this.perimeter = 2(this.length * this.width);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling getPerimeter() to set perimeter of the object, so perimeter will have a default value 0, I suggest you to edit compareTo to call getPerimeter method in its body, as follows:

```
public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
    return Double.compare(this.getPerimeter(), other.getPerimeter());
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
    System.out.println(this.perimeter + " :: " + other.perimeter);//all 0.0 :: 0.0
   return Double.compare(this.perimeter, other.perimeter);
}
```

change the return:

```
return Double.compare(this.getPerimeter(), other.getPerimeter());
```

Comment: Please include some explanation as to why these changes may help the OP